# mbrola issue while using freetts in java

Tags: java, freetts, mbrola

I have used the following code to create voice using FreeTTs and Mbrola.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Voice voice;
    VoiceManager vm = VoiceManager.getInstance();
    System.setProperty(“mbrola.base”, “C:\\mb\\”);
    voice=vm.getVoice(“mbrola_us3″);
    voice.allocate();
    voice.speak(“hello”);
    voice.deallocate();
}
```

I saved the required files in `c:\mb` but I receive the following exception:

```
Exception in thread “Thread-3″ java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice.log(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at    de.dfki.lt.freetts.mbrola.MbrolaAudioOutput.processUtterance(MbrolaAudioOutput.java:58)
at com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice.runProcessor(Voice.java:595)
at com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice.outputUtterance(Voice.java:536)
at com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice.access$200(Voice.java:81)
at com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice$1.run(Voice.java:496)
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 1 minute 54 seconds)
```

Can you help me how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchMethodError at compile time means the method does not exists or the method does not accept the String parameter.

I think its this method - `voice.speak(“hello”);` is the poblem or better you can use a try .. catch block and get the problem result using e.toString()